# How to Load Device Tree From Separate File in U-Boot Image

Tags: linux, u-boot, device-tree, fpga

I'd like to load the device tree from a separate dtb file. So in the end I'd like to end up with the following files on my boot partition:

- BOOT.BIN (first stage boot loader)
- image.ub (U-Boot second stage boot loader including a kernel and a file system)
- system.dtb (device tree that is subject to change often due to the FPGA on the dev board)

Is this even achievable? Any convenient alternatives are also acceptable. For what it's worth I am using a Ultra96 v2 development  board with Petalinux 2019.1.